# Automated Aws Lambda deployment

Tags: bash, aws-lambda, deployment, cicd

We have multiple lambda's deployed on our dev, prod both env and we are using maven as project management.

For lambda deployment, right now,  we package the JAR in zip file and then via S3 we deploy the package.
This is done in local right now, but can be made to cloud (Not a big thing).

Main Issue :

Example :

```
Lambda A{
      method1(){
       LambdaB b = new LambdaB();
        b.method2()
    }
}
LambdaB{
    method2(){
    }
}
```

As you can see method2 in LambdaB is used in Lambda A , so both Lambda A and B both need to be deployed although the change is only made in a single lambda.
How can we know that both lambda's need to be deployed in an automated way , bash scripting might help but I am not sure of it.
Any kind of help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: There are many things wrong with the premise. First off, if you use 'lambdas' like that it won't be another lambda, but just a regular process. Second it's not recommended to call one lambda directly from another (you get charged twice, caller will be idle while it waits). Third this is a 0 downtime deployment and aws doesn't charge for updating lambdas, so why overengineer?

Comment: Hey @Hegi , thanks for answering so quickly
1.We are not calling other lambda from one lambda, (not invoking), just using its method, in another class, consider it as a simple method used by another class
2. My concern is everytime  we change something in code, we need to check where can it impact be , (vs code give us where all in other classes this method is used), need to deploy all those lambda's
This is how the code was written , a lot of refactoring is needed i guess : )